# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS poor video quality

Tags: 12.04, video

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS alongside with Windows 7. It seems like the video quality does not good as in Windows 7. How can I solve this problem?
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: First of all, why are you using version 12.04?  You really should use at least 14.04.

Comment: My hard drive is almost full (10GB free) so I think it's better to use 12.04.

Comment: The minimum hard drive space requirements are about the same for 12.04 and 14.04, so I would recommend reinstalling with version 14.04 if it is a fresh install, or upgrading if it is not a fresh install.

Comment: With 14.04 shall the video quality be improved?

Comment: The video quality issue will probably either be fixed by 14.04 or be fixed by installing a proprietary driver (if you have Nvidia graphics).

Comment: How could I install a proprietary driver?

Comment: Either way, you should upgrade to 14.04, as two years of development is a lot when it comes to open-source software.

Comment: I have Intel® 965GM

Comment: Intel chips do not need proprietary drivers, only Nvidia chips, so you should be good on drivers (though 14.04 probably has a much newer driver version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I install Intel ® Graphics for Linux and get the same video quality as Windows 7. I use the following link:

https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-graphics-installer-1.0-linux

Wow it's awesome.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like GNOME mplayer solves the issue.